# Standard format for Javabean events

Tags: java, events, netbeans, javabeans

I am trying to make a (non-visual) JavaBean that will be a component in several NetBeans forms and the events will fire off actions in those forms. I tried to follow the specifications for events as described in the [Java bean tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/events.html). However, when I stick the bean into a form, it doesn't show the events. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public interface UserListListener extends java.util.EventListener {
    void update();
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class UpdateChecker {
    private ArrayList<UserListListener> userListListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public UpdateChecker(){}

    public void addUserListListener(UserListListener l) {
        userListListeners.add(l);
    }
    public void removeUserListListener(UserListListener l) {
        userListListeners.remove(l);
    }

    void fireUserListEvent() {
        for(UserListListener l : userListListeners) {
            l.update();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [official JavaBeans specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html). What I didn't realize is that the method in the `EventListener` needs to have an `java.util.EventObject` as its argument. Because this is (for some reason) so poorly documented, I am posting a full example for future reference:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class UpdateChecker {
    private ArrayList<UserListListener> userListListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public UpdateChecker(){}

    public void addUserListListener(UserListListener l) {
        userListListeners.add(l);
    }
    public void removeUserListListener(UserListListener l) {
        userListListeners.remove(l);
    }

    void fireUserListEvent() {
        for(UserListListener l : userListListeners) {
            l.updated(new UpdateEvent(this));
        }
    }

}

public class UpdateEvent extends java.util.EventObject {

    public UpdateEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

}

public interface UserListListener extends java.util.EventListener {
    void updated(UpdateEvent evt);
}
```